# tinyMCE 4: add Class to selected Element

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I created a tinymce menu item and what I want it to do is add a class to the selected text element. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Any suggestions? 
Adding my menu item looks like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('button', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addMenuItem('button', {
        icon: '',
        text: 'Button',
        onclick: function() {

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection, 'test'); //not working
        },
        context: 'insert',
        prependToContext: true
    });
});
```

I'd be very thankful for any helpful hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution that may not be perfect (for example, if you select part of a text then this doesn't work as I hoped), but for now it does what I want:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), 'test');
```

if I do this on a link, for example, the scripts add the classname "test" to my  tag.

Comment: In order to toggle class use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.toggleClass`

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.domutils/ describes all available methods

Comment: tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), 'test'); where we want to add this code?

Answer (score 6):

In order to be able to add a class to the editor you need a dom element in the editor to add the class to. Textnodes may not hold a class.
So i propose you insert a span element with the class you want to add wrapped around the actual selection. Be aware that this won't work if the selection leaps over paragraph boundaries (in this case you will need a bit more complicated code). Try this:

```
onclick: function() {
    var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    var content = ed.selection.getContent({'format':'html'});
    var new_selection_content = '<span class="test">' + content + '</span>';
    ed.execCommand('insertHTML', false, new_selection_content);
},
```

Comment: How to show the selected text in a window and provide a textbox to add class in it and then apply to the selected element?

Comment: @RNKushwaha: You can do this using the tinymce code plugin

Comment: Can you provide the link?

Comment: you need to add 'code' to the list of buttons in your tinymce config. Here is the link: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.ui.registry.addButton("addClassBtn", {
    icon: "insertdatetime",
    text: "Highlight ",
    onAction: function (_) {
      var newContent = "<span class='test'>" + editor.selection.getContent() + "</span>";
      editor.selection.setContent(newContent);

    }
  }
}
```